# Calling action of another module in magento through custom module with parameter?

Tags: magento-1.9, module, programmatically

I want to call action of another module with the parameter through my custom module controller action.

Comment: [Here](http://lmgtfy.com/?q=magento+call+module+function) you go Sir.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$this->_redirectUrl()` in controller action for redirect to another controller or external URL.

```
$this->_redirectUrl(Mage::getUrl('custom/index/index', array('parameter_name'=>'value', 'param2'=>'val'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$this->_redirectUrl(Mage::getUrl('frontendname/controller/action', array('param1'=>'value', 'param2'=>'val'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action::_redirect('frontname/controller/action', array('_secure'=>true,'_query'=>'string1=417'));
```

This is also useful when you have to need secure url.